# Solving 4th Degree Polynomial Equation

Tags: polynomials

Solve this Quartic Equation $x^4+3x^3+4x^2+2x+1=0$. I have tried with various possible solution methods. But I can't find the answer.

Comment: Try subtracting this polynomial from (x+1)^4

Comment: All is roots are complex. Even the real and imaginary parts are irrational. So very elementary method will not work. How much do you know on solving quartics ?

Comment: See [quartic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: $LHS>  x^2(x+\tfrac32)^2+(x+1)^2> 0$, so no real roots...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function and its derivatives $$f(x)=x^4+3 x^3+4 x^2+2 x+1$$ $$f'(x)=4 x^3+9 x^2+8 x+2$$ $$f''(x)=12 x^2+18 x+8$$ The second derivative does not show any real root and then it is always positive (so, at most, two real roots). This implies that the first derivative can only cancel once.

Using Cardano method, the first derivative cancels at $$x_*=\frac{1}{4} \left(-3-\frac{5^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{3 \left(9+4
   \sqrt{6}\right)}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{5 \left(9+4 \sqrt{6}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}\right)\approx -0.39417$$ and $$f( -0.39417)\approx 0.673553$$ which is the minimum value of the function.

So, no real root to $f(x)=0$.